# Tkinter Lagging when I click on a button or resize the window while using styles

Tags: python, tkinter, ttkthemes

I have a program and whenever I scale the window or click on a button there is major lag. It only happens when styled (ThemedTk module or style files).

Minimum Reproducible Example

```
from tkinter import ttk
from ttkthemes import ThemedTk

root = ThemedTk(theme="equilux")

root.columnconfigure(tuple(range(4)), weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(tuple(range(4)), weight=1)

ttk.Button(root, text="Top").grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="news", columnspan=4)
ttk.Button(root, text="Top Left").grid(column=0, row=1, sticky="news")
ttk.Button(root, text="Center").grid(column=1, row=1, sticky="news", columnspan=2, rowspan=2)
ttk.Button(root, text="Bottom Left").grid(column=0, row=2, sticky="news")
ttk.Button(root, text="Very Bottom Left").grid(column=0, row=3, sticky="news")
ttk.Button(root, text="Bottom").grid(column=1, row=3, sticky="news", columnspan=3)
ttk.Button(root, text="Bottom Right").grid(column=3, row=2, sticky="news")
ttk.Button(root, text="Top Right").grid(column=3, row=1, sticky="news")

root.mainloop()
```

If I remove the ThemedTk and replace it with a normal tk then it doesn't lag. It didn't lag with built in themes and the only other theme I tried was [Rdbende's Azure Theme](https://github.com/rdbende/Azure-ttk-theme). It only lags with the `rowconfigure` and `columnconfigure`. I want those so everything scales with the screen. The resizing lag isn't much of a issue for what I am making but I can't have it lag when I press a button

Comment: Maybe this is a bug in that theme. Have you tried contacting the author?

Comment: Themes that use a lot of image elements will be slow when having to resize lots of widgets. Each element drawn has a pixmap that is broken into 9 parts and redrawn to make it fit the new area -for every border and highlight and so on. The image element engine was really intended for making new checkbutton checks and such items.

Comment: @patthoyts k. That is probably the problem. I can check later today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***as i understood it's something wrong with ThemedTk module here is the edited code with ttkboosttrap module which is one of the best
> themes and style changers with great futures atm :***

```
from ttkbootstrap import *

root = Window(themename="litera")
root.columnconfigure(tuple(range(4)), weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(tuple(range(4)), weight=1)

Button(root, text="Top",bootstyle='outlined').grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="news", columnspan=4)
Button(root, text="Top Left",bootstyle='outlined').grid(column=0, row=1, sticky="news")
Button(root, text="Center",bootstyle='outlined').grid(column=1, row=1, sticky="news", columnspan=2, rowspan=2)
Button(root, text="Bottom Left",bootstyle='outlined').grid(column=0, row=2, sticky="news")
Button(root, text="Very Bottom Left",bootstyle='outlined').grid(column=0, row=3, sticky="news")
Button(root, text="Bottom",bootstyle='outlined').grid(column=1, row=3, sticky="news", columnspan=3)
Button(root, text="Bottom Right",bootstyle='outlined').grid(column=3, row=2, sticky="news")
Button(root, text="Top Right",bootstyle='outlined').grid(column=3, row=1, sticky="news")

root.mainloop()
```

**> Here is the [website](https://ttkbootstrap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for more informations.**

Comment: Thank you that worked. I will definitely look  more into ttkbootstrap